# Why DRF IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly class permission class allowing Post method

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, coverage.py

I am performing test on Django rest framework,
here is my view,

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,]
    queryset = Post.postobjects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

Url pattern like bellow,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/',PostDetail.as_view(),name="detailcreate"),
    path('',PostList.as_view(),name="listcreate"),
]
```

Here is my test :

```
def create_post(self):

        self.test_category = Category.objects.create(category='django')
        self.test_user = User.objects.create_user(user_name="test_user",password="123456789")
        data = {"title": "new", "author": 1,
                "excerpt": "new", "content": "new"}
        url = reverse('api:listcreate')
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

i ran followiing command:

```
 coverage run --omit='*/myvenv/*' manage.py test
```

and get output :

```
Ran 1 test in 0.215s
OK
```

as my understanding, as here permission class is `[IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,]` , `self.client` should not have permission to `post` and test should Failed. I don't understand what i am missing here. i tried with [IsAuthenticated,] permission and the test was Failed but while using [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,] permission, test is not failing.

Comment: POST method is not considered as "ReadOnly", make sure the user is authenticated.

Comment: so, what should be the outcome of the test ? and why ? @Sumithran

Comment: Okay got it, since your client is authenticated, the client is allowed to post, try the same with an anonymous user in that case test should have failed.

Comment: that is not the case, i tried with [IsAuthenticated,] permission and the test was Failed but while using [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,] class, test is not failing. @Sumithran